# How to improve the below code snippets with list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list-comprehension

I'm trying to convert the below code into efficient way using list comprehension.
I don't want to use While loop in my code.
Problem here is two variables are getting incremented every while and for loop.

Input :

```
string1 = "there is a boy in the lane"
```

Output:

```
['there', 'is', 'a', 'boy', 'in', 'the', 'lane', 
 'there is', 'is a', 'a boy', 'boy in', 'in the', 'the lane', 
 'there is a', 'is a boy', 'a boy in', 'boy in the', 'in the lane', 
 'there is a boy', 'is a boy in', 'a boy in the', 'boy in the lane', 
 'there is a boy in', 'is a boy in the', 'a boy in the lane', 
 'there is a boy in the', 'is a boy in the lane', 
 'there is a boy in the lane']
```

My Code Snippet:

```
import re  
a = "there is a boy in the lane"   
s = re.split("\s",a)   
f_list = []   
for i in range(0,len(s)):   
  l = 0     
  l1 = i+1      
  while(l<len(s)-i):      
    f_list.append(" ".join(s[l:l1]))     
    l = l+1     
    l1 = l1+1     
print(f_list)
```

Can anyone suggest how to implement the above code using list comprehension or any other way without while loop

Comment: A list comprehension always has at most one output for each input. You might need to make use of `itertools` to create all the combinations for you to process in the comprehension.

Comment: itertools combination will create n number of combination, but the required output for me is the combination of next continous words, In simple words, it is first  splitting with one word in first iteration, in second iteration it is splitting into combination of next continous words and so on. Likewise it should give the complete word at last iteration

Comment: There are lots of different functions in `itertools`, you may be able to combine them to get the pattern you want. Otherwise you need to use a loop, not a list comprehension.

Comment: Have you considered using a [generator](https://realpython.com/introduction-to-python-generators/)? This would allow you to generate each item in the output sequence without having to store the whole sequence in memory. Also, I find generator functions easier to read than list comprehensions (or generator comprehensions) when you start getting multiple nested loops.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
a = "there is a boy in the lane"
s = a.split(' ')
f_list = [' '.join(s[j: j+i]) for i in range(1, len(s) + 1) for j in range(len(s) - i + 1)]
print(f_list)
```

Output:

```
['there', 'is', 'a', 'boy', 'in', 'the', 'lane', 'there is', 'is a', 'a boy', 'boy in', 'in the', 'the lane', 'there is a', 'is a boy', 'a boy in', 'boy in the', 'in the lane', 'there is a boy', 'is a boy in', 'a boy in the', 'boy in the lane', 'there is a boy in', 'is a boy in the', 'a boy in the lane', 'there is a boy in the', 'is a boy in the lane', 'there is a boy in the lane']
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this approach

```
from itertools import combinations

string1 = "there is a boy in the lane"
list1 = string1.split()
combo = [' '.join(com) for i in range(1, len(list1) + 1) for com in combinations(list1, i)]
print(combo)
```

Comment: `combinations()` is returning words that aren't adjacent in the input, like `"boy the"`

Comment: this code creates a combination, but those combinations are not a adjacent words. It simply find the combination of all splitted words. My  output will give you 6 to 7 lists .

Comment: all combinations are not required. please see my response below

Answer (score 0):

Get all combinations and check if it is in the string

Code:

```
import itertools

string1 = "there is a boy in the lane"
l_str = string1.split()

result = [' '.join(s) for i in range(1, len(l_str)+1) for s in itertools.combinations(l_str, r=i) if string1.find(' '.join(s)) >= 0]
print(result)
```

Output:

```
['there', 'is', 'a', 'boy', 'in', 'the', 'lane', 'there is', 'is a', 'a boy', 'boy in', 'in the', 'the lane', 'there is a', 'is a boy', 'a boy in', 'boy in the', 'in the lane', 'there is a boy', 'is a boy in', 'a boy in the', 'boy in the lane', 'there is a boy in', 'is a boy in the', 'a boy in the lane', 'there is a boy in the', 'is a boy in the lane', 'there is a boy in the lane']
```